# React Native Firebase Messaging causes lots of ANR's

Tags: react-native-firebase

We are getting lots of ANR's on google play for a React Native App in production. I searched a lot on the internet but all solutions failed. Need help to find a solution.

**ANR**
Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x11000010 pkg=com.appcmp=com.app/io.invertase.firebase.messaging.ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingReceiver (has extras) }

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STPOs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same problem here. There are this thread on github where it called "collateral behavior"...

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/5726

It's very frustrating..

Comment: Same issue here, So far any solution?

Comment: any solutions ? same issue I am getting.. so many ANRs in play store